# Correct syntax for .transform in a Gatling script

Tags: scala, replace, transform, gatling

Warning! I am not a Java coder. I think I am missing the needed gene.

I have a Gatling call that captures a StateToken needed in authentication.

```
.exec(http("00_Access_Site_10")
        // This exec captures the stateToken parameter
        .get("https://sso-cert.johndeere.com/login/login.htm?fromURI=%2Fapp%2Fjohndeerecert_dealerpathcert_1%2Fexkcj9qb4cfudNvLR1t7%2Fsso%2Fsaml")
        .header("Accept:", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3")
        .header("Accept-Encoding:", "gzip, deflate, br")
        .header("Accept-Language:", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
        .header("Sec-Fetch-Site:", "none")
        .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode:", "navigate")
        .header("Sec-Fetch-User:", "?1")
        .check(regex(""""(?<=stateToken":")(.*)(?=","help)""").saveAs("StateToken"))
        //.check(bodyString.saveAs(key = "responseBody"))
      )
```

This works, except in the StateToken string that is captured are characters that need to be converted, i.e. \2D needs to be a hyphen ("-").

This:

```
  .check(regex(""""(?<=stateToken":")(.*)(?=","help)""").saveAs("StateToken"))
  .transform("{StateToken}" => str.replace("\\x2D","-"))
```

Does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[transform](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/#http-check-transform) takes a function with one single parameter which is the original extracted value and returns the transformed result. So the correct syntax is:

```scala
  .transform(str => str.replace("\\x2D","-"))
```

Then, transform is not at the right place:

```scala
.check(
  regex(""""(?<=stateToken":")(.*)(?=","help)""")
  .transform(str => str.replace("\\x2D","-"))
  .saveAs("StateToken")
)
```

Comment: What I am trying to say is that, no matter how I try to use .transform in my situation, I get Errors. .transform is not recognized as a valid function. I cannot find examples on the Web and do not have the needed Java skill to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you, Stephane. I also made that determination on my own, but I would not have gone the right way without your help. You asked me at one point why someone who does not know Java, Maven, Scala, or IntelliJ would even try to follow this path. Well, for the record, I am slowly getting better at all of them. I am still far from "Landelle-Land", but having been pigeon-holed in testing for 20 years, I am getting some of my IT skills back. Thank you for you amazing support.

Comment: Glad I could help and good luck with your journey :) It will work out for sure!